socket.io handshake auth is undefined and not showing auth in handshake
I’m using a Socket.IO server and client application. Below is my client-side code:
this.socket = io("https://my-server-app.cloudapp.azure.com", {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  path: "/nodeserver/socket.io/",
  auth: {
    userId: userId,
    token: token,
  },
});

The Socket.IO server is deployed in an AKS cluster. Here’s the server-side code:
var io = require('socket.io')(app.listen(port), { path: "/nodeserver/socket.io/" });
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("Handshake data:", socket.handshake);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(socket.handshake.auth));
});

Issue
When running the application locally (localhost:8083), the auth variable in the handshake data is populated correctly, as shown in the logs:
Handshake data: {
  headers: {
    host: 'localhost:8083',
    connection: 'Upgrade',
    pragma: 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    upgrade: 'websocket',
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    'sec-websocket-version': '13',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-websocket-key': 'ATD5Ct1HLN3FDAajDfRfIQ==',
    'sec-websocket-extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits'
  },
  time: 'Thu Dec 19 2024 11:36:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
  address: '::1',
  xdomain: true,
  secure: false,
  issued: 1734588404811,
  url: '/nodeserver/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket',
  query: [Object: null prototype] { EIO: '4', transport: 'websocket' },
  auth: {
    userId: 'mymail@mailinator.com',
    token: 'mytoken'
  }
}

However, when accessing the server through the AKS-deployed URL (https://my-server-app.cloudapp.azure.com), the auth field in the handshake data is missing:
Handshake data: {
  headers: {
    host: 'https://my-server-app.cloudapp.azure.com',
    connection: 'Upgrade',
    pragma: 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    upgrade: 'websocket',
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    'sec-websocket-version': '13',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-websocket-key': 'ATD5Ct1HLN3FDAajDfRfIQ==',
    'sec-websocket-extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits'
  },
  time: 'Thu Dec 19 2024 12:20:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
  address: '::1',
  xdomain: true,
  secure: false,
  issued: 1734588404811,
  url: '/nodeserver/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket',
  query: [Object: null prototype] { EIO: '4', transport: 'websocket' }
}

Socket.IO Server: "socket.io": "^4.7.5" and
Socket.IO Client: "socket.io-client": "^4.8.1".
The auth object is passed correctly when testing locally.
It’s not appearing when accessed through the AKS-deployed URL.
Expected Outcome
The auth object should be included in the handshake data for both local and deployed environments.
How can I ensure the auth data is transmitted and logged correctly in the AKS environment?

what type socket.io  auth  did you use and please share the code

Hi I'm using server side socket.io already i mention in above description please find in detail

Socket.IO transmits the auth data in the initial WebSocket handshake but If a proxy or load balancer strips these headers or modifies the handshake, the auth data may be lost.

The issue is Socket.IO transmits the auth data in the initial WebSocket handshake but If a proxy or load balancer strips these headers or modifies the handshake, the auth data may be lost.
Below is an example of how I used proxy-set headers in the ingress.yaml file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "http" 
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "60" 
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-set-header: "Upgrade $http_upgrade"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-set-header.Connection: "upgrade" 
spec:
  ingressClassName: azure-application-gateway 
  rules:
    - host: my-server-app.cloudapp.azure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-server-service
                port:
                  number: 3000

Refer to this link for details about Kubernetes annotations.
For the service.yaml, use the following configuration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: socketio-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: socketio
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP


Make sure add cors and ensure that CORS is configured to allow requests from all domains:
  path: "/nodeserver/socket.io/",
  cors: {
    origin: "*",  
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

Build the image, tag it with Azure Container Registry, and push it to the registry.

Then, create the Kubernetes service using this guide. Use the ACR image to deploy the application to the AKS cluster via a YAML file.
Below is the sample deployment.yaml I used:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: socketio-server
  labels:
    app: socketio
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: socketio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: socketio
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: socketio
        image:samopath.azurecr.io/newfolder2-app:latest

        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production


Connect to your AKS cluster using Azure Cloud Shell, and run the application using Kubernetes. Follow this tutorial for more details.
Check the  Deployment Status by using  kubectl get deployment . Check Pod Status by using kubectl get pods

Lists all services in the current namespace by
kubectl get services.
use  kubectl expose deployment socketio-server --type=NodePort --port=3000 --target-port=3000 to exposing it as a NodePort service.

To Update the socketio-server service to use a LoadBalancer use
kubectl patch service socketio-server -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'

To view logs from a specific pod, use:
kubectl logs socketio-server-865b857564-c2mxx


